# Missing data in ALV demo program(s)

Tags: abap, demo, alv

If I run any of the demo programs whose names start with `SALV_DEMO`, the screens do not show any data.

Example for program `SALV_DEMO_TABLE_SIMPLE`:

[image: Initial screen of SALV_DEMO_TABLE_SIMPLE]

[image: Missing data in SALV_DEMO_TABLE_SIMPLE]

As you can see, there's no data, so impossible to play with sort, filter and so on.

How to add some data?

Answer (score 4):

You have to read the comments at the beginning of the source code.

For instance, there is the following comment for program `SALV_DEMO_TABLE_SIMPLE`:

```
*    If the table ALV_T_T2 is empty, please create data for the demo
*    by running report BCALV_GENERATE_ALV_T_T2
```

The program `BCALV_GENERATE_ALV_T_T2` will fill the tables `ALV_T_T2`, `ALV_CHCK`, `ALV_TAB` and `ALV_CUR`, based on some predefined constants and some random logic.

It should be sufficient to run the program with the default values:

[image: Initial screen of BCALV_GENERATE_ALV_T_T2]

By default, after the data has been inserted into the four tables, it displays the contents of ALV_T_T2:

[image: Contents of table ALV_T_T2 by BCALV_GENERATE_ALV_T_T2]

Most of `SALV_DEMO*` and `BCALV_TEST*` programs are based on these tables.

NB: other demo programs, like `BCALV_GRID*` or `BCALV_EDIT*`, are based on other tables like `SCARR`, `SFLIGHT`, etc., which are filled by another report, `SAPBC_DATA_GENERATOR`.